# Is there a "recent visited folders" in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

In Windows Explorer is there any way I can have a "recent visited folders" features somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This function is contained in widows Explorer itself, Just right Click on the Windows Explorer icon on your taskbar to get it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there any way I can have a "recent visited folders" features somehow?

[xyplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php) provides a "history" of recently visited folders, as well as many other features:

> XYplorer is a tabbed file manager for Windows. It features a powerful file search, a versatile preview, a highly customizable interface, optional dual pane, and a large array of unique ways to efficiently automate frequently recurring tasks. It's fast and light, it's innovative, and it's portable.
>
> - Supported Operating Systems: Windows 10, Server 2014, 8.1, 8, Server 2012, 7, Server 2008, Vista, XP, Server 2003, 2000, NT, Me, 98;
>     32-bit and 64-bit versions.
> - XYplorer is a Portable File Manager. It doesn't require any installation or changes to your system or registry. Take it with you
>     and start it from a USB stick, along with your personal configuration.
>     File management to go.

[image]

There is a freeware version.

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [xyplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free application, [RecentFilesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/recent_files_view.html), though it shows files rather than folders, and only those opened through Windows Explorer or from a standard open/save dialog-box.

*If you wish to instrument specific folders, there's also [FolderChangesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html), which, I believe, utilizes a standard Windows API call to set up a callback on any change to a folder (a handy feature I've used to respond to FTP file delivery).

Apparently Windows 7 and later have a folder, *C:\Users*UserName*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items*, but I find it is unpopulated, perhaps due to options I've selected.