# In Windows, how do I retrieve the data of which folders I most use?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, files-folders

Windows tracks which folders I use then displays the most used one in Quick Access beneath the pinned items.

[image]

How do I retrieve this data?

[1508457](https://superuser.com/questions/1508457/where-does-windows-10-store-the-last-visited-files-recent-folders-and-frequent), [1072785](https://superuser.com/questions/1072785/how-do-i-replace-windows-8-1-frequently-visited-folders-to-recently), [885073](https://superuser.com/questions/885073/is-there-a-recent-visited-folders-in-windows-explorer) do not address this.

Comment: Exactly what data? Just the folder list as it appears in **Explorer**? That's doable in **PowerShell**...

Comment: @KeithMiller I assume windows keeps a count of some kind in order to determine whether one folder is more or less used than another. That data.

Comment: That would most likely be found in the `ms-AutomaticDestinations` file that holds the jumplist data for Explorer. Check my profile for answers ive posted re. Quick Access. I know I've gone into more detail before. As for parsing the file,  the one rhing I know is rhat the file contains a ShellLink structure, the same used for `.lnk` shortcut files.